# SignalR hub.Context.get returns null

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, jwt, signalr

I'm building a chat between specific clients using SignalR and angular client.
I have microservice for JWT token to login, and another microservice for SignalR that is authorized.
So far my app works fine, I'm managing to log in and connect to SignalR with my token. I'm sending from my client the user's name that I want to send the message to, and I want to also send it to myself. The problem is when I'm using -

```
Context.User.Identity.Name
```

I always get null, although I have this claim on my token-

```
new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user.UserName)
```

What am I doing worng?

UserHub:

```
[Authorize]
public class UserHub : Hub
{
    private readonly IHubContext<UserHub> _hubContext;

    public UserHub(IHubContext<UserHub> hubContext)
    {
        _hubContext = hubContext;
    }
 public void  SendMessageToUser(string name, string message)
    {
        var mySelf =Context.User.Identity.Name;     // always null
        _hubContext.Clients.Users(Context.User.Identity.Name, name).SendAsync("GetMessage", message, name).Wait();
    }
```

Token Service (seperate microservice)-

```
 public string? GetToken(string userName, string password)
    {
        var user = _userRepository.GetByUserName(userName);
        if (user != null && user.Password == password)
        {
            var claims = new[]
           {      
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, _configuration["Jwt:Subject"]),
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Iat, DateTime.UtcNow.ToString()),
                new Claim("userId", user.Id.ToString()),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user.UserName),
        };
            var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_configuration["Jwt:Key"]));
            var signIn = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);
            var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
                _configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
                _configuration["Jwt:Audience"],
                claims,
                expires: DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(10),
                signingCredentials: signIn);
     
            return new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);
        }
        else
            return null;
    }
```

Program.cs of Token (parts)-

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
    options.SaveToken = true;
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
    {
        ValidateIssuer = false,
        ValidateAudience = false,
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey=true,
        ValidAudience = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Audience"],
        ValidIssuer = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.Configuration["Jwt:Key"]))
    };
```

Program.cs of SignalR (parts)-

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
    {
        ValidateIssuer = false,
        ValidateAudience = false,
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey=true,
        ValidAudience = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Audience"],
        ValidIssuer = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.Configuration["Jwt:Key"]))
    };
    options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
    {
        OnMessageReceived = context =>
        {
            var accessToken = context.Request.Query["access_token"];
            var path = context.HttpContext.Request.Path;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(accessToken) && (path.StartsWithSegments("/user")))
            {
                context.Token = accessToken;
            }
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Context.User.Identity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)?.Value` or `Context.UserIdentifier`.
`Identity.Name` is for `ClaimTypes.Name`.

Addtionally, `_hubContext.Clients.Users()` by default uses `NameIdentifier` so `Name` wouldn't work even if you had that Claim.

This is customizable and described in the docs at https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/signalr/authn-and-authz?view=aspnetcore-7.0#use-claims-to-customize-identity-handling